# How to detect is UPDATE sql query successed using Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm using Room and i have a method to update a line into Database:

```
@Query("UPDATE packs SET is_opened = 1 WHERE pack_id IN (:packId)")
fun unlockPack(packId: Int)
```

I calling it from Repository:

```
override fun unlockOnePackById(packID: Int) {
        db.packDaoAccess().unlockPack(packID)
    }
```

which called from presener, and then result goes to Activity. When i use GET or another sql queries, i have `Observable` result:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM packs")
fun allFullPacks(): Observable<List<AnimalPackFull>>
```

But as i know, `UPDATE` return nothing. How can i detect, it my `UPDATE` query completed correct? I need it to show popup to User.

Comment: If it does not throw an exception, your `@Query` completed correctly.

Comment: Ok, but what if i want to do smth only when `UPDATE` completed? How can i get callback from my query?

Comment: Your `unlockPack()` call is synchronous. So, do your next bit of work in the next Kotlin statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tweak your query to have some return value of an Int like so

```
@Query("UPDATE packs SET is_opened = 1 WHERE pack_id IN (:packId)")
fun unlockPack(packId: Int) : Int
```

It should return you the number of rows affected by your update query.
Same goes for delete queries